# Using a Node module in a Django / Python app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, npm

I have a fairly classic Python/Django app deployed to Heroku.

There's a pip package I want to use, [django-mjml](https://github.com/liminspace/django-mjml) that itself relies on a Node.js module named [mjml](https://mjml.io/).

My question is how to combine the two? Doing `npm init` and `npm install mjml` created a `node_modules` directory in my root folder, and also the files: `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. I guess that's not really what I want?

Not sure how to proceed from here and any directions are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used that library, but you probably need to [use multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app):

1. Set your main buildpack to `heroku/python`:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
   ```
2. Add the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
   ```
3. Confirm that the Node.js buildpack will run first and the Python buildpack will run second with

   ```
   heroku buildpacks
   ```

Make sure you've got

- a `requirements.txt` file (if you're using `pip`) or both `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` (if you're using Pipenv) committed for your Python dependencies, **and**
- a `package.json` file and either `package-lock.json` (if you're using `npm`) or `yarn.lock` (if you're usng Yarn) committed for the `mjml` dependency.

The `package.json` and `package-lock.json` you mention in your question should suffice for the Node.js dependencies, but they have to be committed, and you need to set the buildpacks before pushing.